# What is wrong with my use of SendInput function?

Tags: c++, windows, sendinput

There is an application running on a Win 10 Ent IoT touchscreen panel PC that adjusts the LED backlighting intensity.  Pressing the 'PAGE UP' key on a hard or soft keyboard or increases the intensity. 'PAGE DOWN' decreases the intensity.

In order to keep the users out of the operating system, my C++ application has a brightness INC and DEC button on the main screen.  The idea is the user presses the buttons on the touchscreen instead of calling up the Windows soft keyboard.

Using examples I found on stackoverflow, my DEC button handler code looks like this.

```
    INPUT input;
    WORD vkey = VK_NEXT; //PAGE DOWN see Virtual-Key Codes in Winuser.h
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(vkey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    input.ki.wVk = vkey;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0; // there is no KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN
    if( SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT)) == 0 )
        // do GetLastError() here
        
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    if( SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT)) == 0 )
        // do GetLastError() here
```

The code compiles and links, but the screen intensity doesn't change when the buttons are pressed.  The SendInput function always returns 1, never 0.

Should I be using a different function? Could the problem be because I'm using a touchscreen?

Comment: Maybe add a slight delay between the two?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput#remarks  "This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level." Wouldn't be surprised if you are hitting that. Can't say for sure though, hence a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but it is (almost always) a bug to call `SendInput()` with `cInputs=1`.  Unless you are performing sleeps between the key presses, you should put the events into an `INPUT[2]` array instead and then pass the whole array to `SendInput()` in 1 call with `cInputs=2`

Comment: To add to what @Frank said, that same page also says: "*This function fails when it is blocked by UIPI. Note that neither GetLastError nor the return value will indicate the failure was caused by UIPI blocking.*"

Comment: Sent input goes to the window with the focus.  So probably your touch screen overlay and not that panel.  You'd have to call SetForegroundWindow() first, that's not pretty.  Ask the IoT vendor for a usable api.

Comment: I guess I should add that the brightness control application running on the Win 10 panel PC is a third-party script written in AutoHotKey.  (I'm not familiar with AutoHotKey.)

Comment: I could be a focus issue.  I can see that when I change a dialog page in my app, the "brightness" (which is actually the color intensity) reverts to what I have programmed.  Once it has drawn, the AutoHotKey app changes the "brightness" back.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 as return value sounds to be good. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), the function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream. If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread.